# Counting frequencies of numbers in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table that would look something like this

```
0.01
0.03
-0.08
0.01
0.02
0.05
0.03
...
```

I would like to group them by frequency in a horizontal table as follows:

```
Number   0.01   0.02   0.03  ...
Freq      2      1      2    ...
```

What's the best way to do this in Excel VBA? In Python, I would use a dictionary, count the frequency, sort them by values and finally output them into a table. I am aware that Excel VBA has a dictionary structure, but it requires "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" and I do not seem to have that in my Excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you're missing a library reference, Scripting Runtime is part of the normal installation it is just not automatically added as a reference to your VBProject.

You can do this with late-binding:

```
Dim dict as Object
Dim cl as Range, rng as Range
Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

Set rng = Range("A1:A10000") 'modify as needed
For each cl in rng.Cells
    dict(cl.Value) = dict(cl.Value) + 1
Next
```

WIth early binding you need to enable a reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime, and that would allow you to like below, and also expose the intellisense:

```
Dim dict as Scripting.Dictionary
Set dict = New Scripting.Dictionary 'Instead of CreateObject
```

Dictionaries do not have a built in Sort method.  You could perform the sort on the worksheet (use the macro recorder to get the proper syntax) and then iterate to add the values to the dictionary, etc.

Chip Pearson has produced some functions that cleverly sort arrays [here](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/VBAArrays.htm) but for your purposes you want the procedures that can sort collections/dictionaries, [HERE](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/CollectionsAndDictionaries.htm)

I've used pretty much all of these reliably in the past.  IN terms of lines of code, there's a lot more "overhead" than with Python, but just tuck these functions in their own module and call them as needed.